# Row name of the smallest element

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting

I have the following dataframe:

```
d <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,4), b=c(20,19,18,17))
row.names(d) <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
```

I want another data.frame, with the same columns and 2 rows, which contain the row names of the 2 smallest elements in that column.

In the example the expected result would be:

```
# Expected results
exp <- data.frame(a=c("A", "B"), b=c("C","D"))
```

Comment: Fixed! I want to sort the column in ascending order, and take the row names of the first 2 rows. This must be done for every column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We loop over the columns with `lapply`, `order` the values, use that index to subset the `n` corresponding `row.names` of 'd', and wrap with `data.frame`

```
n <- 2
data.frame(lapply(d, function(x) sort(head(row.names(d)[order(x)], n))))
```

-output

```
#  a b
#1 A C
#2 B D
```

---

With `R 4.1.0`, we can also use the `|>` operator for chaining the functions (applied in the order for easier understanding) along with `\(x)` - for lambda function in `base R`

```
# //  ordered the column values
# // get corresponding row names
lapply(d, \(x) row.names(d)[order(x)] |>  
             head(n) |>  # // get the first n values
             sort()) |>  # // sort them
      data.frame() # // convert the list to data.frame
#  a b
#1 A C
#2 B D
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
d %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(),
      ~ sort(head(row.names(d)[order(.)], n))))
#  a b
#1 A C
#2 B D
```

Comment: Thank you! Why you substituted the subsetting with `head`?

Comment: @robertspierre because you can pass `n` as a parameter instead of `[1:2]` or `[1:3]` etc.

Comment: Clear. Thank you very much. I am going to accept all your answers tomorrow when the system let me :)

Comment: WOW! R 4.1.0 was released 5 days ago ... I have 4.0.3. You are updated :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `sapply` in base R -

```
rn <- rownames(d)
sapply(d, function(x) rn[order(x) %in% 1:2])

#      a   b  
#[1,] "A" "C"
#[2,] "B" "D"
```